# Track progress of file upload to google cloud storage via js?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I'm wondering if it is possible to track the progress of a file upload to google cloud storage when using the javascript client? As I have a progress bar that I would like to show to the user on how much of the file has been uploaded so far.

I'm using the same upload code that google gives on their [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-javascript/blob/master/index.html#L259) page for file upload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the `gapi.client.request` api provided by the js library I instead created an `XMLHttpRequest` and appended a event listener for the event `progress`. As seen by the following:

```
      const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        var metadata = {
          'name': 'testing',
          'mimeType': contentType
        };

        var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
        var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

        gapi.client.request()
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?uploadType=multipart&key=apiKey&alt=json', true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
          var pc = parseFloat(e.loaded / e.total * 100).toFixed(2);
        }, false);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        };

        xhr.send(multipartRequestBody);
```

**Attribution:** Majority of code was taken from Google's js library with the only addition being the event listener for listening to the progress of the upload.