# Get file uploading progress with Google Cloud Storage using NodeJS REST API

Tags: node.js, file-upload, progress-bar, google-cloud-storage, multipartform-data

I am using @google-cloud/storage npm package for file upload from NodeJS. It is uploading file to google cloud bucket successfully.
Reference: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/tree/storage-1.1.0#cloud-storage-ga

But for larger files(size > 20 MB), I need to show upload progress status on browser(Client - Chrome, firefox, etc).

I am submitting AJAX request with file as formdata to REST API(written using NodeJS) and REST API uploads file to Google Cloud Storage buckets.
**Note:** *I don't want to upload files directly from UI(Browser) to Google cloud storage.*

But, I am not getting how to send back uploading file progress to UI from Google-Cloud-Storage via NodeJS REST API.

Would appreciate your suggestion or relevant references.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use XMLHttpRequest to track your progress on NodeJS, using an eventlistener
2. Open a socket and transmit progress messages from your event listener and consume them on the client

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30635818/4465100
2. http://blog.fossasia.org/file-upload-progress-in-a-node-app-using-socket-io/

Comment: isn't there a native way to do that?